# strstr: behavior different using different versions of gcc

Tags: c, gcc, strstr

I'm porting a program that works with Ubuntu 8.04 (gcc version 4.2.4) to 10.04 (gcc version 4.4.3). I have the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {
  char p[100] = "////abcd";
  char *t;

  /* Remove duplicate slashes, saving only one of them */
  while (t = strstr(p, "//"))
    strcpy(t, t + 1);

  printf("%s\n", p);

  return 0;
}
```

The result should be `/abcd`, which it is with gcc 4.2.4. With 4.4.3, the output is `/accd`.

Can you suggest me a code change that will give the correct output using both versions of gcc, and preferrably explain what is going on here.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You've just been lucky.

From the [`strcpy`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/strcpy.html) documentation:

> The strcpy() function shall copy the string pointed to by s2 (including the terminating null byte) into the array pointed to by s1. **If copying takes place between objects that overlap, the behavior is undefined.**

The strings overlap in your case, your program invokes undefined behavior.

A possible reason why it used to work but no longer does is that `strcpy` could have been implemented as a builtin by GCC like `memmove` (i.e. safe in this situation), but this changed to a non-safe version for performance reasons. (This is pure speculation.)

To fix it, use [`memmove`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/memmove.html) rather than `strcpy`, with something like:

```
while (t = strstr(p, "//")) {
  memmove(t, t+1, strlen(t)); // strlen(t)'s bytes worth of data
                              // will cover the string bytes left
                              // and the \0 terminator
}
```

That's not terribly efficient, but it will work portably - `memmove` has to handle overlapping memory areas.

Comment: Johan was **unlucky** before compiling with gcc 4.4.3

Comment: Cool. The codebase is stuffed with similar usages. :) So, now I've implemented my own strcpy to solve the problem. Thanks!

Comment: What @pmg said.  We should all be blessed with bugs that present themselves in easily observable fashion, instead of lying dormant for years.